# Where should i create my static methods?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, static

I need to create the below static method. Does this need to be in a particular folder (App_Code or Models), or should i create a new folder for this? Is there a particular convention i should follow?

```
public static DbGeography CreatePoint(double lat, double lon, int srid = 4326)
{
    string wkt = String.Format("POINT({0} {1})", lon, lat);

    return DbGeography.PointFromText(wkt, srid);
}
```

Also, would i need to specify a new 'using' in my controller to call this?

Comment: Not really, although this looks like a helper method of sorts, so I'd be inclined to create a 'Helpers' folder in your project, and keep it there.
The 'using' will depend on the namespace that your static method resides in. If it's the same as wherever you are calling it from, then you won't need another using. If it isn't, you will :)

Comment: As no one else has answered, I have expanded my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Method placement

There are not really any hard and fast rules.

In your case, the code appears to be a type of helper method. On a small, single project application I'd be inclined to create a 'Helpers' folder, and create a static class there, containing methods like this.

You have a dependency on the PointFromText method in the DbGeography class, so this would also need to be moved.

Infact, PointFromText sounds like it performs the same task as CreatePoint, but taking a different input.
It would make things cleaner to [create an overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229029.aspx) of CreatePoint

```
DbGeography CreatePoint(string wkt, int srid); 
DbGeography CreatePoint(double lat, double lon, int srid = 4326);
```

You can now call CreatePoint using either a latitude/longitude, or an appropriate string/srid.

### Using Directive

The [using directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) will depend on the namespace that your static method resides in:

```
namespace Foo
{
    public static class HelperMethods
    {
        public static DbGeography CreatePoint(double lat, double lon, int srid = 4326)
        {
            string wkt = String.Format("POINT({0} {1})", lon, lat);

            return DbGeography.PointFromText(wkt, srid);
        }
    }
}
```

With the above example, in your calling code you will have a few options. You may

1) call the method directly:

```
Foo.HelperMethods.CreatePoint(51.5, 0.1);
```

2) Import the namespace with a using directive, and call the method:

```
using Foo;
...
HelperMethods.CreatePoint(51.5, 0.1);
```

3) Import the static class and access the methods directly:

```
using static Foo.HelperMethods;
...
CreatePoint(51.5, 0.1);
```

It's really down to your preference which approach you take, I'd probably go for the second option just to aid readability slightly.

Comment: This has worked perfectly, thanks ever so much for your detailed explanation and example.